# Cosmic Software C Compiler Cant open header file

Tags: compiler-errors, header, include

I am trying to compile a C file using Cosmic Software (IDEA V2.9f) but keep getting a "Can't open MotFlash.h" error even though this header file is in the same folder with the C file.

```
#include "MotFlash.h"
```

This is the first time I am using this compiler. Do I need to configure anything to open a header file?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you add comment your platform (Windows/mac/linux/...) and add a relevant tag for the compiler?  It looks like a compiler configuration issue, and this may be both platform and compiler dependent...

Comment: I am running the compiler on Window XP 2002.